# Django Auth Ldap on Windows

Tags: django, ldap

Is there any way to make `django ldap authentication` I am trying to `pip install django-auth-ldap` but keep getting

```
Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

then I searched and find [this project](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap) but those settings configuration wont work. Reading docs. but when I try to install ldap but it isn't working...
Any help would be appreciated,

thanks from now :)

I've tried installing `django-auth-ldap` and `django-python3-ldap` but neither installing or configuring didn't work...

Comment: post the full install trackback

Comment: posting as answer to question

Comment: you can edit your question instead of posting answers, you are missing openldap headers for it to compile, you can instead install precompiled from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap

Comment: thank you, from here ı was be able to find the meaning of wheels, and I find the newer version of those wheels [here](https://github.com/cgohlke/python-ldap-build?tab=readme-ov-file)

Answer (score 0):

> Collecting django-auth-ldap   Obtaining dependency information for
> django-auth-ldap from
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/2b/9c566a9cdf675f3cb919c0c6b806217764cf17bea2600777900656d2fb05/django_auth_ldap-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
> Using cached django_auth_ldap-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.2 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: Django>=3.2 in
> c:\users\tp054591\desktop\taha polat
> projeler\aralıkprojeleri\251223proje\venv\lib\site-packages (from
> django-auth-ldap) (5.0) Collecting python-ldap>=3.1 (from
> django-auth-ldap)   Using cached python-ldap-3.4.4.tar.gz (377 kB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build
> wheel ... done   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
> Requirement already satisfied: asgiref>=3.7.0 in
> c:\users\tp054591\desktop\taha polat
> projeler\aralıkprojeleri\251223proje\venv\lib\site-packages (from
> Django>=3.2->django-auth-ldap) (3.7.2) Requirement already satisfied:
> sqlparse>=0.3.1 in c:\users\tp054591\desktop\taha polat
> projeler\aralıkprojeleri\251223proje\venv\lib\site-packages (from
> Django>=3.2->django-auth-ldap) (0.4.4) Requirement already satisfied:
> tzdata in c:\users\tp054591\desktop\taha polat
> projeler\aralıkprojeleri\251223proje\venv\lib\site-packages (from
> Django>=3.2->django-auth-ldap) (2023.3) Requirement already satisfied:
> pyasn1>=0.3.7 in c:\users\tp054591\desktop\taha polat
> projeler\aralıkprojeleri\251223proje\venv\lib\site-packages (from
> python-ldap>=3.1->django-auth-ldap) (0.4.8) Collecting
> pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5 (from python-ldap>=3.1->django-auth-ldap)
> Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181 kB) Using
> cached django_auth_ldap-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB) Building wheels
> for collected packages: python-ldap   Building wheel for python-ldap
> (pyproject.toml) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Building wheel for python-ldap (pyproject.toml) did not run
> successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [80 lines of output]
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
> copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
> copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> copying Lib\ldap_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls\vlv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> copying Lib\ldap\controls_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\controls
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\extop
> copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\extop
> copying Lib\ldap\extop\passwd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\extop
> copying Lib\ldap\extop_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\extop
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\schema
> copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\schema
> copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\schema
> copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\schema
> copying Lib\ldap\schema_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ldap\schema
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest
> copying Lib\slapdtest_slapdtest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest
> copying Lib\slapdtest_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest
> running egg_info
> writing Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing requirements to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt
> writing top-level names to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> no previously-included directories found matching 'Doc.build'
> adding license file 'LICENCE'
> writing manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\README -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gencerts.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gennssdb.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\slapdtest\certs
> running build_ext
> building '_ldap' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Modules
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe"
> /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS
> -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.4.4 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules
> "-IC:\Users\TP054591\Desktop\Taha Polat
> Projeler\AralıkProjeleri\251223Proje\venv\include"
> -IC:\Users\TP054591\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\TP054591\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
> LDAPObject.c
> C:\Users\TP054591\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yhgpzk_2\python-ldap_4b43108342e74575943141d88568f131\Modules\common.h(15):
> fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'lber.h': No
> such file or directory
> error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit code 2
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
> Failed to build python-ldap ERROR: Could not build wheels for
> python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based
> projects